# AngularJS select input ng-model access in controller function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this select on my page:

```
<select multiple id="userId" class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selectData.currentUser"
                ng-options="user.id as user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName for user in ctrl.users"
                ng-change="ctrl.getProducts()">
        </select>
```

And i have this AngularJS Controller:

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$http", "$routeParams", function($http, $routeParams) {
    var self = this;

    var selectData = {
        currentUser: "test"
    }

    self.getUsers = function() {
        $http.get("users/all").then(function(response) {
            self.users = response.data.items;
        })
    };

    self.getProducts = function() {
        $http.get("products/all?userId=" + self.selectData.currentUser).then(function(response) {
            self.products = {"count": response.data.count, "items": response.data.items};
        });
        self.userChoosed = true;
        alert(self.selectData.currentUser);
    };

    self.addProduct = function() {
        alert(self.addForm.title + " CU:" + self.selectData.currentUser);

        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "products/add",
            data:"title=" + self.addForm.title + "&description=" + self.addForm.description + "&price=" + self.addForm.price + "&ownerId=" + self.selectData.currentUser
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            alert("success");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("error" + response.data);
        });

    };

}]);
```

In addProduct function of controller i can't get  a selectData.currentUser. It works fine in getProducts function(this function load items from database using selectData.currentUser, and it really works, i can see it), but it doesnt in addProduct.

Its a function for Form submitting. So, when i click my "Submit" button, it's does nothing. But if i delete "CU: " + self.selectData.currentUser in alert function, it works and shows my alert(but of course it doesnt send correct post request to server).

What should i do? Why ng-submit does nothing when i call it with selectData.currentUser in alert function inside?

Comment: a plunker would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you do not share full controller code, but why you use `self` context to access your data in `selectdData` object?

You can use direct call to `selectData` as this declared o top of your controller and thanks to closure can be accessed using just `selectedData.currentUser`.

```
alert(self.addForm.title + " CU:" + selectData.currentUser);
```

Comment: I done so. Now it works and alert function is OK, but selectData.currentUser = "test", it's default value. Another functions still have actual value of ng-model in selectData.currentUser

Comment: Move your `selectedData` into scope. Instead of `var selecteData = ...` use `self.selectedData = `. And this will work using old syntax `self.selectData.currentUser`

Comment: Now my selectData is `self.selectData = `. It works with self.selectData.currentUser syntax, but its value is default("test"), its not ng-model of select value

Comment: Please take a look on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/ADukg/8838/. Does it represent simplified version of your controller (omitting http). Here `ng-model` works as expected? I'm showing alert on selecting.

Comment: Yes, that works good. 

In my getProducts() function, alert and all code works as expected, and it have actual value of ng-model, not "test". Your fiddle works fine here.

But in my addProduct() function, ng-model's value is always "test", default value.

Comment: Please add to your code example those code block when you use `addProduct` functionality. Or recheck - maybe you use `ng-controller` directive twice so your scope data reinitialized

Comment: thank you! I use ngRoute module in this app, and my error was that i use `ng-controller` two times, in my main application and in my `ng-view`. So now it works perfect!